# Distinct $0,1$ symmetric circulant determinants

Tags: combinatorics, determinant

If $M$ is a circulant integer matrix of size $n\times n$ whose entries are randomly chosen from $\{0,1\}$ value, how many different determinants does $M$ possibly take value in?

If $M$ is symmetric and circulant, then what is the count?

Comment: If the entries are randomly chosen, the determinant takes exactly one value. It makes no sense to introduce randomness when you're interested in the count of the possible distinct values.